# jquery: addClass, removeClass: animation works only once: why?

Tags: jquery, css

When I use that:

```
$("#passwordConfig").removeClass('shake animated').addClass('shake animate');
```

This works only ONCE.

I need to add some timeOut to make it run as many times as I want!

```
$("#passwordConfig").removeClass('shake animated');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("#passwordConfig").addClass('shake animated');
                    }, 50);
```

Any idea why ?

CSS:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
}
```

Comment: Ye, try [.toggleClass()](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/kzhx9ur4/)

Comment: That's because no ui repaint is called between classes toggling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because removeClass and addClass happening so quickly it doesn't allow the DOM to catch up per say. You can do something like this if you really hate setTimeout:

```
$("#passwordConfig").removeClass('shake animated').delay(50).queue(
    function (next) {
        $(this).addClass('shake animated');
        next();
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/51dwhd2o/

Toggle class is fine too but seems like it would only work every other call of toggle.

Comment: No need to delay it, just force ui repaint in some way between toggling classes, e.g http://jsfiddle.net/51dwhd2o/1/ I cannot test it currently on other browser than chrome but webkit browsers are well known to optimize ui repainting, sometimes too much as it seems to be the case here

Comment: Oh cool, I didn't know that would work. Learned something while answering! Always great. Thanks! Although in jQuery 3.0 don't think that will work without giving some sort of time. I know they made massive breaking changes to hide show in the latest version.

Comment: Ya on jq 3.x (and 1.x as i can test it) needs to be `.hide().show(0)` or any better way im not aware of to force ui repainting